LWC button does not work on touch screen
I am trying to use a simple lwc button but on a touch screen windows laptop, the button never gets clicked and I am not sure why. There are not console issues
button code
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save and Create Report" title="Save and Create Report" disabled={isSaveDisabled} onclick={handleSaveClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
When used with trackpad , the button can be clicked. Just with touch screen it does not work on same machine

what browser are you using? and can you click other standard salesforce buttons?

It was an issue with my canvas app which was trying to capture some signatures.
